# Which (non get/kiddushin) shtaros exist on a d'oraisa level?

Tags: legal-documents, deorayta

Besides a get (written explicitly in the Torah [Deuteronomy 24:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.24.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) & a shtar kiddushin (learned from a get via a *hekesh* [Kiddushin 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.5a.3?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en))- **are there other shtaros that exist on a  d'oraisa level, and if so which ones**?

(minority opinions also welcome- ie Rabbeinu Tam/ Ri are of the opinion that a ketubah is d'oraisa [Tos' Ketubot 10a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.10a.1?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Ketubot.10a.1&lang2=bi))

Comment: IINM they don't think the Ketubbah document is Deorayta, just the monetary obligation

Comment: What Shtar is not valid Deorayta? Halvah, Tenayim, you name it. All work biblically, or else collecting with them would be stealing. You seek examples of something that is ubiquitous. If you have some reason to think what you seek is somewhat unique or limited, please [edit] it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not including the ones mentioned in the OP, the documents for buying any of the following are d’Oraisa:

- **Jewish slaves** ([Kiddushin 16a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.16a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), either from comparison to Kiddushin based on [Shemos 21:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.16a.2?lang=bi&p2=Exodus.21.10&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0) or from a combination of [Shemos 21:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.16a.4?lang=bi&p2=Exodus.21.7&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0) and [Vayikra 25:46](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.16a.5?lang=bi&p2=Leviticus.25.46&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0))
- **Non-Jewish slaves** ([Kiddushin 22b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.22b.7-8?lang=bi), from comparison to land based on [Vayikra 25:46](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.22b.7?lang=bi&p2=Leviticus.25.46&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0))

  - **Bill of emancipation** (Kiddushin 23a and [Gittin 41b](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.41b.13-14?lang=bi), by Geziras HaKasuv from Gittin in [Devarim 24:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.41b.14?lang=bi&p2=Deuteronomy.24.1&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0) to [Vayikra 19:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.41b.14?lang=bi&p2=Leviticus.19.20&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0))
  - Even **freeing half a slave** ([Gittin 41b](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.41b.2-3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), by comparison to freeing a slave through money based on [Vayikra 19:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.41b.3?lang=bi&p2=Leviticus.19.20&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0))
- **Land given as a gift** ([Kiddushin 26a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.26a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), from [Yirmiya 32:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.26a.7?lang=bi&p2=Jeremiah.32.11&lang2=bi))
- **Movable property acquired via land** ([Kiddushin 26a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.26a.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), from [Divrei HaYamim 2:21:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.26a.13?lang=bi&p2=II_Chronicles.21.3&lang2=bi))

Comment: Great answer thanks! Do you if there are any other or is this primarily it?

Comment: @alicht I'm sure there are others, but this is probably most of them. I knew most of the potential answers to your question would be scattered throughout האשה נקנית, so it wasn't too difficult to track this down. Another place to look is the second half of שנים אוחזין in Bava Metzia, where all sorts of documents are mentioned. I don't recall any Gemaras there which quote any pesukim to justify their existence. Hard to tell whether they're d'Oraisa and those Gemaras just aren't addressing that, or if they're d'Rabbanan or communally accepted as binding (minhag hamakom or dina d'malchusa).

Comment: Right- your answer has ones that are explicitly learned, but surprised there's no list online about those that are/aren't